# Particle System ignoring my vertex group density

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, vertex-groups

I've seen similar questions like mine, but I couldn't get their answers to work for me. Basically, I'm making a glass and I want a particle system to generate condensation on a specific area of the glass. I created a vertex group, but when I add the particle system, it doesn't seem to take the vertex group into account at all. However, it does seem to acknowledge my vertex group, but only when I negate it (so the particles spawn everywhere, BUT the vertex group. I don't know how to go about fixing this.

[image: Vertex Group]

Here is where I get lost:

[image: Confused]

I know my little collection of droplets isn't perfect, but that's a separate issue. I'm just trying to get them to emit from the faces in my vertex group. Any help is appreciated! I'll upload my .blend file shortly.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because vertex groups only consider vertices, not faces, so the influence of a vertex will extend until the next vertex:

[image]

We can see it if we switch to Weight Paint mode:

[image]

So what you need to do is create additional edge loops where you want the particles to stop, and make sure thay are not part of the vertex group:

[image]

Here is what it will give:

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to change the influence via weight painting?